# subtracting numeric fields from a date field

Tags: sql, oracle, date

i have a tenure field (numeric) on a table representing the number of months a user has been on file.   I want to subtract that field from today's date to return the registration date of the user.  Any idea how to do this using oracle sql

Comment: Whole months? Subtracting the value (with `add_months()`) will give you today's day, the 23rd, in whatever the month was. Which is odd, but not as odd as trying to track that number in a column in the first place, rather than the actual registration date, which won't change... how is it being maintained, you add 1 to each value every month?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
add_months(sysdate, -your_number_of_months_column)
```

? You may possibly want to use trunc(sysdate).

However, it sounds like a bad design; why is the registration date of the user not stored in its own column? If you select the user's record today, the registration date will be different than if you selected it tomorrow (unless you use trunc(sysdate, 'mm')).

Answer (score 0):

`ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1 * tenureMonths)`